# Authenticate in Azure

Tags: azure, authentication

Currently AD is in on-premises & Authentication is in place for this Application.
I would like to migrate this ASP.Net application(from on-premises) to Azure VM(IaaS).  How this authentication & Authorization of this application can be done when one AD is in On-premises & other AD is not existing in Cloud?

Answer (score 1):

In order to access on-prem resources, you will need to establish a site-to-site VPN between Azure and your on-prem datacenter.

See [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal/) for more information.

The other option is to use ADConnect to sync AD(on-prem) with Azure Active Directory.  You would then have to update you application to use Azure Active Directory as an authentication source.

See [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect/) for more information.

Lastly, you could try using Azure AD Domain Services to act as an AD in Azure and keep the authentication the same in your application.

See [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-ds/) for more information.